# ITK in Python: SimpleITK or not?

Tags: python, c++, image-processing, itk

I have started to work with `ITK` for a week thanks to `SimpleITK` in `Python`. Even though, currently, I am satisfied with `SimpleITK`, I have noticed that some features such as the `Powell optimization scheme` or the `OnePlusEvolutionary` one are not available in `SimpleITK`. It seems to be the same with landmark-based registration methods.

So, I was wondering if there is a way to retrieve all the features available in `ITK` (in `C++`) in `SimpleITK` or if it is necessary to perform my own wrapping?

If not I will later learn `C++` to do so!

Thanks!

Comment: for image processing, did you took a look at skimage or opencv?

Comment: I took a look at skimage as it has several features-based detectors (SIFT, SURF, ORB,...) which can be useful in my case. Regarding OpenCV, ITK offers much more functionnalities about image registration.

Comment: You could place a feature request to add the additional optimizers: http://www.itk.org/Wiki/SimpleITK#Issue_Tracking_And_Feature_Requests Also what is the reason these optimizers are required and the current ones do not meet your requirements?

Comment: It was just to try different methods, some being gradient-based while others are heuristic-based (ants, genetic algorithms, simplex). However, simplex and Powell's methods are implemented in the NiPy library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. SimpleITK is limited in functionality. It is however possible to access the entire ITK library in Python using the WrapITK interface. This is an old interface which I don't believe has been updated for a while. However, it is still possible to compile new builds from source and use WrapITK.

The process is not exactly smooth. I have done the build on a Windows machine in the past and had then noted some of the not-so-smooth-steps that I had to encounter. I'll lay those down here. Since you haven't mentioned your OS, I'm going to go ahead explain the setup for Windows. Let's see if you're able to get it up and running.

- ITK-4.6 + Python2.7 + CMake + VS2008 professional (all 32-bit)
- Nothing later than VS2008 can compile GCCXML, which is required for generating python bindings
- After configuring CMAKE, the following flags need to be additionally set:

  - `ITK_WRAP_PYTHON`
  - `ITK_WRAP_*` (all types: float, double, etc.)
  - `ITK_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` (gets automatically set if first flag is set)
- In VS2008, build in Release mode only. Number of projects in the project explorer will be more than 500. Around 300-350 should get built.
- When building, make sure that you have an accessible internet conection for downloading GCCXML (which will likely get downloaded after you have started the build in VS2008). There should be no error while verifying the download. If there is, it might be because of directory creation permission errors.
- The project should get built with *NO ERRORS*
- Copy the `WrapITK.pth` file from the ITK `build/Wrapping/Generators/Python/Release` to `Python/Lib/site-packages`
- Add the following to your `Path` variable:

  - `C:\ProgramLibs\ITK\build2008\lib\Release`
  - `C:\ProgramLibs\ITK\build2008\bin\Release`
  - `C:\ProgramLibs\ITK\build2008\lib`
- Now ITK should work properly (below is a test python file that you can use to run a sanity check on the build). Except every time you call `itk.Image` the first time in your program or on the Python interpreter, there are a dozen warnings and they take time to execute that. This is a known issue. Once you are past this, it's smooth.

---

Test file

```
import itk
pixelType = itk.UC
imageType = itk.Image[pixelType, 2]
readerType = itk.ImageFileReader[imageType]
writerType = itk.ImageFileWriter[imageType]
reader = readerType.New()
writer = writerType.New()
reader.SetFileName("<input image file location>")
writer.SetFileName("D:/Output.png")
writer.SetInput( reader.GetOutput() )
writer.Update()
```

Comment: I haven't tried yet, but with the newest version there is no limitation on the compiler, because GCCXML has been replaced http://kitware.com/blog/home/post/888

Comment: I didn't know about this. Good news indeed!

Answer (score 0):

There is also WrapITK, which is a python wrapping of ITK that you can enable to compile with ITK (so, you'll have to compile it by yourself but you will not need to code the warpping at least). See http://kitware.com/blog/home/post/888, http://www.itk.org/Wiki/ITK/Wrapping , http://www.itk.org/Wiki/ITK/Release_4/Wrapping/WrapITK_Installation.t .

Note however that probably not all filters are wrapped (http://www.itk.org/Wiki/Proposals:Increasing_WrapITK_Coverage#List_of_Unwrapped_Filters , last updated in 2009 so probably now the situation is better).
The only compiled wrapITK package I came across is Devide-RE https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-b1zS536R2M (with an older version of ITK, 3.2 if I remember correctly), but maybe also Slicer and Vistrail have it (http://www.itk.org/pipermail/insight-users/2009-August/031910.html)